# R: stacking up values from rows of a data frame

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I started programming in R yesterday (literally), and I am having the following issue:

-I have a data frame containing R rows, and each row contains N values.
Rows are identified by the first and second field, while the other N-2 are just numerical values or NA.

-Some rows have identical first field and identical second field, something like:

```
row 1: a,b, third_field, .. ,last_field
row 2: a,b, third_field, .. ,last_field
```

the rule is that usually the first line will have its fields containing some numbers and some NA, while the second row will contain NA and numbers as well, but differently distributed.

What I am trying to do is to merge the two rows (or records) according to these two rules:

1) if both rows have a NA on a given field, I keep NA

2) if one of the two has a number, I use that value; if both of the rows contain the same value, I keep it also.

How do you do this without looping on each field of each row? (1M rows, tenths of fields, it will finish maybe tomorrow).

I do not know how to better explain my problem. I am sorry for the lengthy explaination, thanks a lot.

EDIT: it is better if I add an example. The following two lines

```
a,b,NA,NA,NA,1,2 ,NA
a,b,NA,3 ,NA,1,NA,NA
```

should become

```
a,b,NA,3 ,NA,1,2 ,NA
```

Comment: Try `dplyr::coalesce(x, y)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @H1, it actually did it. I am wonndering, is there a way to let it do the same, but on a full data table? I mean, imagine I have a table full of rows made in this way, is there a similar function that will act on the whole table?